# Method for taking screenshot in selenium framework using c#

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver, nunit

I am actually new in developing framework using selenium c#.
Here is my problem. I usually know how to take screenshot as below,

```
ITakesScreenshot screenshotDriver = driver as ITakesScreenshot;
Screenshot screenshot = screenshotDriver.GetScreenshot();
screenshot.SaveAsFile("c:/test.png", ImageFormat.Png);
```

But if i want to create a separate method for screenshot and call it whenever i need a screenshot how can i achieve it.

It would also be great, when the test case is pass or fail i might need to capture the screenshot.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: What is preventing you from having the code you have posted as a method that accepts parameters?

Comment: Hi IanSoc, I think i would need a method that i can call with parameters. Would you help me what parameters can i pass? apart from browser driver, could you suggest which parameters will benefit me?